# Testing android app on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, tablet, galaxy

I am developing an android app with eclipse on my mac. I want this to be an app that will run on any android device, but the only one I have available is a Samsung Galaxy Tablet. I have tried running the app on the device by turning on USB Debugging and downloading android file transfer, but when I run the app in eclipse it still defaults to the virtual device. Can anyone explain how to run an app on a samsung galaxy tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just had to restart the tablet and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the device is connected and try from the command line: `adb devices`. If it does not appear then the device is not seen, perhaps you should install the drivers.

(`adb` is located in `~/android sdk/platform tools`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). If everything is set up properly, Eclipse should give you the option to run the app on your device:

> If using Eclipse, run or debug your application as usual. You will be presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you want to install and run the application.